# Uploading a liquid map file to integration account using devops

Tags: azure-devops, liquid, azure-integration-account

Is there a way to upload a liquid map file to an existing integration account in azure using DevOps?

The only way i have found so far is to add the liquid map directly to the integration account ARM template, but this is time consuming & error prone as characters have to be escaped & the map can be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

you can upload using azure CLI

```
New-AzIntegrationAccountMap -MapFilePath 'clouddrive/Schema1.xslt' -MapName 'Schema1' -MapType Xslt -Name 'IntegrationAccount31' -ResourceGroupName 'ResourceGroup11'
```